# Julia Plots-GR, export to PDF, retain text editability

Tags: julia, julia-plots, gr

I am trying to save some figures I made in Julia (Plots package, GR backend) to PDFs and I love the aesthetics + being able to save as vector graphics. However, I may need to invariably tweak things in Illustrator. When in Matlab, the plots exported as PDF are by default editable, e.g. it is an easy few clicks to replace all fonts. Something similar can also be done for [`matplotlib`](https://jonathansoma.com/lede/data-studio/matplotlib/exporting-from-matplotlib-to-open-in-adobe-illustrator/).

So my **question**: how can I export to PDF with *editable text* (this means something like Illustrator will treat text as text instead of paths) using the default backend?

Googling around, it seems the same `matplotlib` hack above might work in Julia via `Plots.pyrcparams`, but I am afraid to change backends and then have to fix a dozen plots because things broke.